# Excel: how to add row as per each hour between two different time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I searched a lot to figure out how to add rows in between two rows based on the time and date, but unfortunately I could not find any formula. I really appreciate it if anybody can help me.

As you can see in the picture, I had column  *J*  which is  *Date and Time*  and column *M* which is *Result*.

To make my work easier I added two columns *K* and *L* which are *Date* and *Time* respectively.

[image: example picture]

I want to look at the first two rows in column *L* and if there is any **hour missed between them**, then add one row for each hour and put the cell in column *Result* to "0".

In the previous picture, there are two hours missed between *00:00* and *3:00*, so I want excel to add two new rows between them and add "0" in column "M".

Also check, if there is one day missed between two rows then add 24 rows between them. for example I need 50 new rows between *January 1,2010 11:00* and *January 3,2010 14:00* and the result zero for each row in column *M*.

The final result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Between the last two entries, there are almost 7,000 hours.  Are you talking about adding that many rows?  Actually, wouldn't this call for inserting rows for every hour between the first and last date/times?

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  It sounds like you're asking to produce a table with 1/1/2010 midnight as the first entry, then roughly 8,500 rows in one hour increments, with 12/19/2010 19:00 as the last row, and the 10 date/times corresponding to your example filled in.  Is that correct?

Comment: As fixer1234 commented, from a technical standpoint, this is very bad design. Usually, when storing data you try to *avoid* storing this amount of 0 data. This smells like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why do you want to do this Excel 'trick'? (Note: the fact that you have all this data in an Excel sheet instead of a database already smells as bad design)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this macro:

```
Public Sub fillHours()
theEnd = False
i = 2
timecolumn = 7
While theEnd = False:
    firstDate = Me.Cells(i, timecolumn - 1)
    If firstDate <> "" Then
        secondDate = Me.Cells(i + 1, timecolumn - 1)
        If firstDate = secondDate Then
            firstHour = Me.Cells(i, timecolumn)
            secondHour = Me.Cells(i + 1, timecolumn)
            diffHour = ((secondHour * 24) - (firstHour * 24)) - 1
            If diffHour > 0 Then
                For j = 1 To diffHour
                    Rows(i + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
                    newHour = Str(i + j - 1) & ":00"
                    newHour = Right(newHour, Len(newHour) - 1)
                    Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn) = newHour
                    Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn - 1) = Me.Cells(i, timecolumn - 1)
                    Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn + 1) = 0
                Next j
            End If
        ElseIf firstDate < secondDate Then
            diffDate = secondDate - firstDate
            maxInsertedRows = diffDate * 24
            firstHour = Me.Cells(i, timecolumn)
            secondHour = Me.Cells(i + 1, timecolumn)
            diffHour = ((secondHour * 24) - (firstHour * 24)) - 1
            If diffHour < 0 Then
                diffHour = (23 - (firstHour * 24)) + (secondHour * 24)
                realInsertedRows = maxInsertedRows - (24 - diffHour)
            Else
                realInsertedRows = maxInsertedRows - diffHour + 2
            End If
            For j = 1 To realInsertedRows
                Rows(i + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
                basicHour = i + j - 1
                divbasicHour = Int(basicHour / 24)
                basicHour = basicHour - (divbasicHour * 24)
                newHour = Str(basicHour) & ":00"
                newHour = Right(newHour, Len(newHour) - 1)
                Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn) = newHour
                Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn + 1) = 0
                If newHour <> "0:00" Then
                    Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn - 1) = Me.Cells(i + j - 1, timecolumn - 1)
                Else
                    Me.Cells(i + j, timecolumn - 1) = Me.Cells(i + j - 1, timecolumn - 1) + 1
                End If
            Next j

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Else
        theEnd = True
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Open Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, double click the sheet in the left side and paste the code on the right side. Check that the value in the line `timecolumn = 7` matchs with the number of column of your **Time** column.

Comment: But it seems the code does not work. Maybe I dont know how to apply it. I will upload the desire file I want to get. (Note: the cells with value zero in column "C" are the rows that I want to add to my files.

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/sHgY/Example.xlsx

Comment: What does happen with the macro? It generates an error? Does it generate some rows but not all?

Comment: jcbermu, actually I copied and pasted the Macro(as you said) then Run the program, but I see no reaction, nothing, happening to the file. Do I nee to change something in the code according to my file? Do I need to do something else after running the code? Or I just need to copy and paste it the run! I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: @mohammad Sorry, it was my mistake, I corrected the Macro so you can now copy and paste it. You have to modify the value of the variable in the line that says `timecolumn = 7` to the number of column that is your **Time** column.